# Where is export ssis packages location

Tags: sql-server, ssis

One of the SSIS package giving error in SQL Agent. I went to Integration Services in SQL Server, I right click on SSIS Package stored in Stored Packages > MSDB and clicked Export Package. Location: SQL Server, Server name (done), Package Path (Package Name) and then OK... All went fine but where this export package gone, where I can find and test? I tried to do search for package name on server but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have overwritten your source package. It seems that you are exporting the package to the default location, which is the location of the source package. I'm trying your steps with one of my packages, and I'm getting an "are you sure to overwrite" message.
Try to export the SSIS to another location (using SQL Server store) or to filesystem, in order to check whether the package will be saved.